# Value shift when parsing through the separator

Tags: java, parsing

At some moments, the values of the columns change for me. In the attachments I put the input file and the output file after parsing

[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPqLZ.png)

[After parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPt5y.png)

I first used the separator in the form ","

```
 private static List<Row> getCsvRow(Path csvPath) {
    try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(csvPath)) {
      return lines
          .map(str -> str.split(","))
          .map(Converter::mapCvsRow)
          .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }
  }
 try(var outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(excelPath)) {
      workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

Then I did it, but it still causes me to move the data in the columns

```
 private void csvToXlsx(Path csvFilePath, Path excelFilePath) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Converting CSV to XLSX" + excelFilePath);
        List<CSVRecord> records = collectAllEntries(csvFilePath);
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(excelFilePath.toString()));
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet();
        IntStream.range(0, records.size())
                .forEach(rowNum -> {
                    XSSFRow myRow = mySheet.createRow(rowNum);
                    CSVRecord record = records.get(rowNum);
                    for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                        XSSFCell myCell = myRow.createCell(i);
                        myCell.setCellValue(record.get(i));
                    }
                });
            myWorkBook.write(writer);
            writer.close();
        }
```

Also I have this method

```
 public List<CSVRecord> collectAllEntries(Path path) throws IOException {
        List<CSVRecord> store = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
                Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL)
        ) {
            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                store.add(csvRecord);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return store;
    }
```

Comment: DON'T REINVENT THE WHEEL.  Use a CSV parsing library. CSV is more complex than it looks at first glance.

Comment: @JimGarrison Can you write me how to do it? I also added the method that I use before the this method